# SignOut Using Retrofit and Shared Preference

Tags: android, retrofit2

I would like to do Signout function in my android application. First, I use retrofit to do login and now, I want to logout using retrofit.I am passing Authrazation Token, in header if i don't use Token in then i will get This error  "**getting response http/1.1, code=403, message=Forbidden,url=https:/auth/user/logout**". How to do Logout using Retrofit and Also i having getting response **http/1.1, code=403, message=Forbidden,url=https://auth/user/logout**,even after passing token, Response body getting null,its showing. What to do?

> Postman Header File[image]
> [image: Bearer Passing In Header File]

**ProfileFregment**

```
              signout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            SessionMaintain.init(getActivity());
            //read string in shared preference.

            String token = SessionMaintain.read(SessionMaintain.TOKEN_USER, null);
            Integer userId = SessionMaintain.read(SessionMaintain.USER_ID, 0);

    
            logout(userId,token);

        }
    });

}

private void logout(Integer userId,String authorization) {
    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<LogResponse> logoutCall = apiInterface.signOut(userId,authorization);
    logoutCall.enqueue(new Callback<LogResponse>() {
       
       @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LogResponse> call, Response<LogResponse> response) {

          Log.d("LogResponse",response.toString());
            if(response.isSuccessful()){

                LogResponse lresponse = response.body();
                lresponse.getMessage();



                Log.d("Token","Response"+response.body().getMessage());
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                SessionMaintain.clear();


            }
        }
```

**Shared Preference**

```
public static String read(String key, String defValue) {
    return mSharedPref.getString(key, defValue);
}

public static void write(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mSharedPref.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString(key, value);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}

public static boolean read(String key, boolean defValue) {
    return mSharedPref.getBoolean(key, defValue);
}

public static void write(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mSharedPref.edit();
    prefsEditor.putBoolean(key, value);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

**Model**

```
 @SerializedName("message")

public String message;
```

**ApiInteraction**

```
                     @FormUrlEncoded
                   @POST("auth/user/logout")
     Call<LogResponse> signOut(@Field("user_Id") Integer user_id,
                          @Header("Authorization") String authorization);
```

Comment: can you please elaborate? what's exactly your issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** that you need to clear your user session data when you got a success response from your logout http call.

Add the following function to your `SessionMaintain` class:

```
public static void clear() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mSharedPref.edit();
    prefsEditor.clear();
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

and use it when you get a success response from your log out service, like this:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<LogResponse> call, Response<LogResponse> response)
{
    Log.d("LogResponse", response.toString());
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        // here
        SessionMaintain.clear()
    }
}
```

Comment: @mhwajeeh- I have getting one more issue, Response i have getting http/1.1, code=403, message=Forbidden, url=https://xxxxx.com/auth/user/logout}, That y I am using Token , but still getting this error.

Comment: Can you help me out with this issue please

Comment: Are you sure your sending your token with proper header form, for token authentication I believe you should add the header in this form: `Authorization: Bearer <token>`

Comment: So try changing your call to add `'Bearer '` string to the token, like this,      
  `apiInterface.signOut(userId,"Bearer " + authorization);`

Comment: In Header File , I am passing Like this (Authorization: Token <token no>) Otherwise response is not coming.

Comment: I tried changing apiInterface.signOut(userId,"Token " + authorization) instead of 'Bearer',but now its getting internal server issue code=500

Comment: That means you solved the authorization error, but some error happened on server-side. You need to check server code that is handling your request.

Comment: I mean in postman reponse is coming like this through Header File, in android reponse body is still Null.

Comment: Try to send the same request on postman, are you getting http 500 response error?

Comment: In postman through bearer not working,but (Authorization: Token <token no>)like this working, in android i m trying same thing through "Token" but result giving me code=403 forbidden. I m getting stuck.

Comment: How are you adding the authorization header in postman?

Comment: So what happens when you replace 'Token' with 'Bearer' in your header value?

Comment: Shared with bearer

Comment: Is there an extra space after 'Bearer' string?